# Maximizing a computationally expensive function

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, sampling, optimization

Let $f:[0,1]^{80} \rightarrow [0,1]$ be some function, and say I have a computationally expensive way to calculate $f(x)$ for each $x \in [0,1]^{80}$ (expensive = 40s per query).

The goal is to maximize $f$ - any advice?

My ideas so far are:

1. Gradient Descent - numerically approximating the gradient at each point along the way with a few samples. This method is problematic since queries are so expensive (therefore, I can't properly approximate the gradient).
2. Approximation - sampling $m$ values $x \in [0,1]^{80}$ and calculating $f(x)$, approximating $f$ using some regression model on these $m$ values, maximize the approximation function (which will have a computable gradient), hoping that the maximizing $x$ will approximately maximize $f$.

Comment: People have used 2. with 'Gaussian Processes' as a regression method in order to optimize hyperparameters (for examples, of neural nets) and obtain better models in some Kaggle competitions. See https://arimo.com/data-science/2016/bayesian-optimization-hyperparameter-tuning/.

Comment: There is also a gradient-free optmization method for non-linear functions, see package `BB` in R.